# Difference between Job and Deferred in Coroutines Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, deferred, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to coroutines, I understand `launch` and `async` but still confusing part is `Deferred`. What is `Deferred`? and difference between `Job` and `Deferred`. Clear explanation and example is more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So `job` is sort of an object that represents a coroutine's execution and is related to [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952), e.g. you can cancel a job, and all the children of this job will be also cancelled.

From [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/):

> Job is a cancellable thing with a life-cycle that culminates in its completion.

`Deferred` is some kind of analog of `Future` in Java: in encapsulates an operation that will be finished at some point in future after it's initialization. But is also related to coroutines in Kotlin.

From documentation:

> Deferred value is a non-blocking cancellable future — it is a Job that has a result.

So, `Deferred` is a `Job` that has a result:

> A `deferred` value is a `Job`. A `job` in the `coroutineContext` of `async` builder represents the coroutine itself.

An example:

```
someScope.launch {
    val userJob: Deferred<User> = async(IO) { repository.getUser(id) }
    //some operations, while user is being retrieved 
    val user = userJob.await() //here coroutine will be suspended for a while, and the method `await` is available only from `Deferred` interface
    //do the job with retrieved user
}
```

Also, it is possible to structure this `async` request with an existing scope, but that is a talk of another question.

Comment: Thanks llyunin, can explain with piece of code-snipets more helpful

Comment: @MageshPandian, I've edited the answer.
Also, `Deferred` interface is also extended with some another convenient methods, but they are for now marked as experimental (Kotlin 1.3)

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out differences in [exception handling](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html) which might be significant in some use cases; `launch` is throwing immediately while `async` throws exceptions as a "result" when calling `await()`.

Comment: @Pawel There's yet another important point: `async` also immediately cancels its parent job, which then propagates cancellation to all other `async` tasks. This happens whether or not you `await` on it. You can prevent this by using `SupervisorJob` as a parent, but that would be abuse of the mechanism.

Answer (score 18):

On a basic level, `Deferred` is a future. It makes it possible for one coroutine to wait for the result produced by another one, suspending itself until it's ready. Calling `async` is one way, but by far not the only way, to get a `Deferred`.

However, I think your question is more about the basics: when to use `launch`, when to use `async-await`. Here's an important lesson: **you probably don't need async**. People tend to use it because the keywords `async` and `await` are familiar from other languages, but in Kotlin, `async` is not a general-purpose tool to achieve non-blocking calls.

Here's a basic recipe on how to turn a blocking call into a suspending, non-blocking one:

```
uiScope.launch {
    val ioResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { blockingIOCall() }
    ... just use the result, you're on the GUI thread here.
}
```

Comment: one use case of using async is, you can use multiple parallel calls using async and await them all, whereas withContext is blocking, and hence multiple parallelism is not achievable using it only.